# creating a chat activity in android

Tags: java, android, chat, onkeylistener

1. After declaring and creating the `textWatcher` object, I would like to disable the send button and set it to gray if the `chatText` (edit text) is empty
2. I think it's a problem of ranking. Please help.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

       list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
       list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
       chatText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
       //chatText.setOnKeyListener(this);

       me = true;
       send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
       change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);



       list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

       adp =  new TheAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.chat);

       list.setAdapter(adp);

       chatText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
       checkFieldsForEmptyValues();


       send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               envoyer();
           }

       });

       change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               me = !me;
               if (!me) {
                   change.setText(R.string.sender2);
               } else {
                   change.setText(R.string.sender);
               }
           }
       });
   }





   public void envoyer(){

       adp.add(new messages(me, chatText.getText().toString()));
       chatText.setText("");
   }

   private  void checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){

       String s1 = chatText.getText().toString();

       if (s1.length() < 0 ) {
           send.setEnabled(false);
       } else {
           send.setEnabled(true);
           send.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
           //send.setBackgroundColor((getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)));
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Format your code properly. And specify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onTextChanged` is where you would check to see if the text field is empty:

```
chatText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) { //enable}
            else if (s.length() == 0 { //disable }
```

In your code, you have `if (s1.length() < 0 )` which I don't think will ever be true because the text size will never be less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Disable on init
    send.setEnabled(false);

    // add text changer
    chatText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Enable when input is != null and not empty. You can check string lenght too
            send.setEnabled(s != null && !s.toString().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

disable button before and add textwatch. You can also check if edittext value is not empty or verify string length.

I hope it will help you